# Can I get gem details as json on rails-assets.org like in rubygems.org?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Debian has a gemwatch service that dynamically converts a gem to tar.gz (see http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-ruby-extras/gemwatch.git/tree/gemwatch.rb)

I'm trying to extend this functionality to include gems from rails-assets.org. But it seems rails-assets.org does not provide per gem details like rubygems.org (`http://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/#{gemname}.json`)

If I can get the version, I can construct the download url. Do I have to parse whole http://rails-assets.org/specs.4.8.gz

Comment: Just asked rails-assets.org folks https://github.com/rails-assets/rails-assets/issues/271